# Passing macro as a CString reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, atl, c-strings, msdn

I'm analyzing a crash on my application and I suspect my current approach(Approach 1 in the code pasted below) could result in a crash,but not sure.
I have pasted below my code for reference. Crash is not reproducible in-house and no dumps either.

```
#define SAMPLE_STRING L"Hello world"

class CFoo
{
    std::map <CString, CString> m_map;
public:
    void SetMyString(__in const CString&  csParam)
    {
        CString csKey(L"Mykey");
        m_map[csKey] = csParam;
    }
};
int main()
{
    //approach 1
    CFoo obj;
    obj.SetMyString(SAMPLE_STRING);


    //approach 2
    CFoo obj;
    CString csMystr(SAMPLE_STRING);
    obj.SetMyString(csMystr);

}
```

Below are my questions:

1. Can we pass the macro as a CString reference or should we create a CString intialize with the macro and then pass the reference of the CString?
2. What is the difference between the above two approaches?
3. Could the application crash with approach 1? If it could, Can someone please explain how?

Comment: this code is compiling with approach 1?

Comment: `Crash is not reproducible in-house and no dumps either.` so how do you know this is the source of problems? You need crash dump/log, or at least application logs to have any clue what is the problem, if you can't reproduce it. Your code sample looks valid.

Comment: Your macro case is exactly the same as `obj.SetMyString(CString(L"Hello world"))`. It's entirely unproblematic and not the source of your problems.

Comment: There is no difference between both approaches. In case 1 conversion is done silently in case 2 explicitly.

Comment: On a side note, there is no need for a macro here. I suggest to write `constexpr wchar_t SAMPLE_STRING[] = L"Hello World";`. If your compiler doesn't have `constexpr`, write `const wchar_t* const SAMPLE_STRING = L"Hello World";`

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said, source of problem was at a differnt place. Thanks everyone for the quick response.The problem was reproduced and it helped fixed the crash. Source of problem is ,was reading a file which has english and japanese characters into an CStringA variable, while trying to do a makelower it crashed. Literally japanese characters was converted to junk in CStringA.
CString makelower was the source of problem.